# How do I pass a function name to a callback?

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to jQuery and Javascript so this may be simple.

I have a function that calls a service using `$.ajax()`. The service calls work correctly but now it's time to go back and cleanup a few things. For example, whenever I call the service, I create a new function and copy / paste a bunch of code. Bad practice, I know, but I was prototyping.

I'd like to have a single function that calls the service and pass that function the names of the callback functions. In the code below, I want to pass the names of the functions to be called on success, error, and complete. I also want to the arguments to be passed to the functions. For example, I want the function `GetCurrentPricing` to be called on success and I want the response to be passed to the `GetCurrentPricing` function.

How do I do this?

```
function CallTheService() { 

    $.ajax(
        {
        url         : varUrl,
        type        : varType,
        cache       : varCacheBool,
        data        : varData, 
        contentType : varContentType,
        processdata : varProcessData, 
        dataType    : varDataType, 
        async       : varAsync,
        success     : function(response) {},
        error       : function(err) {},
        complete    : function() {}
        }
    )

}
```

Comment: Maybe consider passing the functions themselves as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call the function at:

```
success: function(response){
GetCurrentPricing(response)
},
```

Thats what those options are for :)

Comment: or even more simply: `success: GetCurrentPricing, ...`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
success: function(response) {GetCurrentPricing(whateverparameters)},
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
var success = function(response) { alert(response); };

function CallTheService(success) { 

    $.ajax(
        {
        url         : varUrl,
        type        : varType,
        cache       : varCacheBool,
        data        : varData, 
        contentType : varContentType,
        processdata : varProcessData, 
        dataType    : varDataType, 
        async       : varAsync,
        success     : function(response) { success.call(response); },
        error       : function(err) {},
        complete    : function() {}
        }
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var successFunction = function(response) { GetCurrentPricing(); };

function CallTheService(successFunction) { 

    $.ajax(
        {
        url         : varUrl,
        type        : varType,
        cache       : varCacheBool,
        data        : varData, 
        contentType : varContentType,
        processdata : varProcessData, 
        dataType    : varDataType, 
        async       : varAsync,
        success     : successFunction,
        error       : function(err) {},
        complete    : function() {}
        }
    )

}
```